# How get data having relationships between tables using Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I have an **API with Laravel**, and I have decided to **use relations between tables**, I have related them using these functions in all migrations:

```php
// Migration file: 2020_05_26_185555_create_customers_table.php on line 27
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

And then I've implemented functions like the following: 
(which get the records it's related to):

```php
// Model app\User.php on line 80
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

On **Customers controller**, How can I use the function to show above to list all the clients of that user** , that is, replace the following code:

```php
// Controller Customer\CustomerController.php on line 17
public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $customers = Customer::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    return $this->showAll($customers, 200, $filters);
}
```

For something like the following (Just an example, it doesn't work, but it's the idea of ​​what I mean):

```php
// Controller Customer\CustomerController.php on line 17
public function index()
{
    $customers = User::customers(); // Ejemplo
    return $this->showAll($customers, 200, $filters);
}
```

My goal is to create relationship between relevant table, example, a user's clients** , without using a condition, like my current implementation of code.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `$customers =  Auth::user()->customers;` should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dynamic property for the relationship to access it (and have it loaded):

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $customers = $user->customers;

    ...
}
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)